# Jetpack Compose TopAppBar flickers after setting BottomNavView with Navigation component

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Working on a Jetpack Compose app with a `BottomNavigationView` and Navigation component, I did the usual setup for the bottom bar inside the activity:

```
val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

In each screen I am using a composable `TopAppBar`.
Unfortunately, after adding the `setupWithNavController` call, the `TopAppBar` started flickering in all the navigation bar destinations (but not in deeper destinations).

How can I fix the flickering?

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue. What helped, to my surprise, was lowering `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose version` to `2.4.0-alpha04`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer you exactly how to fix the flickering, but I can tell you that the recommended way to work with a Navigation component, TopBars and BottomBars in Jetpack Compose, is to use the [Scaffold component](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/material/scaffold/) and the [navigation-compose component](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation).

**Compose Navigation component dependency:**

```
// Navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha09"
```

It is still in alpha, but so far it has been working really well. Just try to keep posted about all updates.

**Example usage:**

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                    Text(text = "App Title")
                }
            }
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    TextButton(onClick = { navController.navigate("home") }) {
                        Text(text = "Home")
                    }
                    TextButton(onClick = { navController.navigate("favorites") }) {
                        Text(text = "Favorites")
                    }
                    TextButton(onClick = { navController.navigate("profile") }) {
                        Text(text = "Profile")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        NavHost(navController, startDestination = "home") {
            composable("home") {
                Home()
            }
            composable("favorites") {
                Favorites()
            }
            composable("profile") {
                Profile()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am currently constrained to use Fragments along with Navigation component on this project, so this is not an option, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: The TopAppBar flickers even if you use the Compose Navigation library.