# Jetpack Compose application-wide conditional TopAppBar best practice

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have an Android Jetpack Compose application that uses `BottomNavigation` and `TopAppBar` composables. From the tab opened via `BottomNavigation` users can navigate deeper into the navigation graph.

### The problem

The `TopAppBar` composable must represent the current screen, e.g. display its name, implement some options that are specific to the screen opened, the back button if the screen is high-level. However, Jetpack Compose seems to have no out-of-the-box solution to that, and developers must implement it by themselves.

So, obvious ideas come with obvious drawbacks, some ideas are better than others.

The baseline for tracking navigation, as [suggested](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav) by Google (at least for `BottomNavigation`), is a `sealed` class containing `object`s that represent the current active screen. Specifically for my project, it's like this:

```
sealed class AppTab(val route: String, @StringRes val resourceId: Int, val icon: ImageVector) {
    object Events: AppTab("events_tab", R.string.events, Icons.Default.EventNote)
    object Projects: AppTab("projects_tab", R.string.projects, Icons.Default.Widgets)
    object Devices: AppTab("devices_tab", R.string.devices, Icons.Default.DevicesOther)
    object Employees: AppTab("employees_tab", R.string.employees, Icons.Default.People)
    object Profile: AppTab("profile_tab", R.string.profile, Icons.Default.AccountCircle)
}
```

Now the `TopAppBar` can know what tab is opened, provided we `remember` the `AppTab` object, but how does it know if a screen is opened from within a given tab?

### Solution 1 - obvious and obviously wrong

We provide each screen its own `TopAppBar` and let it handle all the necessary logic. Aside from a lot of code duplication, each screen's `TopAppBar` will be recomposed on opening the screen, and, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66638286/jetpack-compose-topappbar-flickers-after-setting-bottomnavview-with-navigation-c) post, will flicker.

### Solution 2 - not quite elegant

From now on I decided to have a single `TopAppBar` in my project's top level composable, that will depend on a `state` with current screen saved. Now we can easily implement logic for Tabs.

To solve the problem of screens opened from within a Tab, I extended Google's idea and implemented a general `AppScreen` class that represents every screen that can be opened:

```
// This class represents any screen - tabs and their subscreens.
// It is needed to appropriately change top app bar behavior
sealed class AppScreen(@StringRes val screenNameResource: Int) {
    // Employee-related
    object Employees: AppScreen(R.string.employees)
    object EmployeeDetails: AppScreen(R.string.profile)

    // Events-related
    object Events: AppScreen(R.string.events)
    object EventDetails: AppScreen(R.string.event)
    object EventNew: AppScreen(R.string.event_new)

    // Projects-related
    object Projects: AppScreen(R.string.projects)

    // Devices-related
    object Devices: AppScreen(R.string.devices)

    // Profile-related
    object Profile: AppScreen(R.string.profile)
}
```

I then save it to a `state` in the top-level composable in the scope of `TopAppBar` and pass `currentScreenHandler` as an `onNavigate` argument to my Tab composables:

```
    var currentScreen by remember { mutableStateOf(defaultTab.asScreen()) }

    val currentScreenHandler: (AppScreen) -> Unit = {navigatedScreen -> currentScreen = navigatedScreen}
```

```
// Somewhere in the bodyContent of a Scaffold
                when (currentTab) {
                    AppTab.Employees -> EmployeesTab(currentScreenHandler)
                // And other tabs
                // ...
                }
```

And from inside the Tab composable:

```
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController, startDestination = "employees") {
        composable("employees") {
            onNavigate(AppScreen.Employees)
            Employees(it.hiltViewModel(), navController)
        }
        composable("employee/{userId}") {
            onNavigate(AppScreen.EmployeeDetails)
            Employee(it.hiltViewModel())
        }
    }
```

Now the `TopAppBar` in the root composable knows about higher-level screens and can implement necessary logic. But doing this for every subscreen of an app? A considerable amount of code duplication, and architecture of communication between this app bar and a composable it represents (how the composable reacts to actions performed on the app bar) is yet to be composed (pun intended).

### Solution 3 - the best?

I implemented a `viewModel` for handling the needed logic, as it seemed like the most elegant solution:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AppBarViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    private val defaultTab = AppTab.Events
    private val _currentScreen = MutableStateFlow(defaultTab.asScreen())
    val currentScreen: StateFlow<AppScreen> = _currentScreen

    fun onNavigate(screen: AppScreen) {
        _currentScreen.value = screen
    }
}
```

Root composable:

```
    val currentScreen by appBarViewModel.currentScreen.collectAsState()
```

But it didn't solve the code duplication problem of the second solution. First of all, I had to pass this `viewModel` to the root composable from `MainActivity`, as there appears to be no other way of accessing it from inside a composable. So now, instead of passing a `currentScreenHandler` to Tab composables, I pass a `viewModel` to them, and instead of calling the handler on navigate event, I call `viewModel.onNavigate(AppScreen)`, so there's even more code! At least, I maybe can implement a communication mechanism mentioned in the previous solution.

### The question

For now the second solution seems to be the best in terms of code amount, but the third one allows for communication and more flexibility down the line for some yet to be requested features. I may be missing something obvious and elegant. Which of my implementations you consider the best, and if none, what would you do to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I use a single TopAppBar in the Scaffold and use a different title, drop-down menu, icons, etc by raising events from the Composables. That way, I can use just a single TopAppBar with different values. Here is an example:

```
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    var canPop by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var appTitle by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var showFab by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var showDropdownMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var dropdownMenuExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var dropdownMenuName by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var topAppBarIconsName by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val tourViewModel: TourViewModel = viewModel()
    val clientViewModel: ClientViewModel = viewModel()

    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, _, _ ->
        canPop = controller.previousBackStackEntry != null
    }

    val navigationIcon: (@Composable () -> Unit)? =
        if (canPop) {
            {
                IconButton(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "Back Arrow"
                    )
                }
            }
        } else {
            {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        scaffoldState.drawerState.apply {
                            if (isClosed) open() else close()
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = null)
                }
            }
        }

    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        drawerContent = {
            DrawerContents(
                navController,
                onMenuItemClick = { scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.close() } })
        },
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(appTitle) },
                navigationIcon = navigationIcon,
                elevation = 8.dp,
                actions = {
                    when (topAppBarIconsName) {
                        "ClientDirectoryScreenIcons" -> {
                            // search icon on client directory screen
                            IconButton(onClick = {
                                clientViewModel.toggleSearchBar()
                            }) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search,
                                    contentDescription = "Search Contacts"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (showDropdownMenu) {
                        IconButton(onClick = { dropdownMenuExpanded = true }) {
                            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.MoreVert, contentDescription = null)

                            DropdownMenu(
                                expanded = dropdownMenuExpanded,
                                onDismissRequest = { dropdownMenuExpanded = false }
                            ) {

                                // show different dropdowns based on different screens
                                when (dropdownMenuName) {
                                    "ClientDirectoryScreenDropdown" -> ClientDirectoryScreenDropdown(
                                        onDropdownMenuExpanded = { dropdownMenuExpanded = it })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        },
...
   ) { paddingValues ->

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(paddingValues)

        ) {
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = Screen.Tours.route
            ) {
                composable(Screen.Tours.route) {
                    TourScreen(
                        tourViewModel = tourViewModel,
                        onSetAppTitle = { appTitle = it },
                        onShowDropdownMenu = { showDropdownMenu = it },
                        onTopAppBarIconsName = { topAppBarIconsName = it }
                    )
                }
```

Then set the TopAppBar values from different screens like this:

```
@Composable
fun TourScreen(
    tourViewModel: TourViewModel,
    onSetAppTitle: (String) -> Unit,
    onShowDropdownMenu: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    onTopAppBarIconsName: (String) -> Unit
) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        onSetAppTitle("Tours")
        onShowDropdownMenu(false)
        onTopAppBarIconsName("")
    }
...
```

Not probably the perfect way of doing it, but no duplicate code.

Comment: I can see that you are using somewhat of a combination of solution 2 (passing down event handlers) and solution 3 (view model that also implements communication). I generally don't like solution 2 because of passing a handler to a composable for it to just be passed down again and so on. But I now know that view model way of implementing communication is not cringe and also used. Thanks!

Comment: You can pass viewModel, navigation, etc to the first level of your screens, but no need to pass them down farther. Use state hoisting instead and handle the actions of the lower-level screens from the top level. That way, you don't need to pass resources everywhere, which is the recommended way.

Comment: `.addOnDestinationChangedListener` should occur in a `LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = { ...addOnDestinationChangedListener(...) }` or similar to prevent it from being _added_ on each re-composition

Answer (score 1):

Since I want having the same challenge and wasn't too happy with the solution that was given here I (might) have found another way to attack this problem.
Actually it's that simple, that I'm not sure if it's actually a good idea. If you find reasons why this isn't a good solution please let me know!

First of I created a state class for the TopAppBar (for simplicity I'm just using a title property) and a provider object:

```kotlin
data class TopAppBarState(val title: String? = null)

object TopAppBarStateProvider {
    var topAppBarState: TopAppBarState by mutableStateOf(TopAppBarState())
    fun update(topAppBarState: TopAppBarState) {
        this.topAppBarState = topAppBarState
    }
}
```

In my main screen I'm using it like this:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                TopAppBarStateProvider.topAppBarState.title?.let { title ->
                    Text(
                        text = title,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                }
            }
        )
    }
) {
    // Content
}
```

Now in every screen I want to show I just call:

```
TopAppBarStateProvider.update(TopAppBarState(title = "My updated title"))
```

That's it. Comments are welcome!

Comment: Uh, you're doing it as a side effect?