# Compose - get the same instance of ViewModel inside and outside of Navigation Graph

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, jetpack-compose-navigation

The top-level composable in my Compose app is structured like this:

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(/*...*/) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            when (currentScreen) {
                /*...*/
            }
        },
        content = {
            AppNavigation(navController)
        },
        bottomBar = {
            // Bottom navigation
        }
    )
}
```

Since I am using `BottomSheet` together with `BottomNavigation` I cannot delegate handling the former to the screens from `AppNavigation` because it will break Material Design guidelines (`BottomSheet` will be shown above the `BottomNavigation`).

Top bars of my screens are also separate from the screens themselves as per [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69421064/jetpack-compose-application-wide-conditional-topappbar-best-practice)

And of course since bottom sheet that is tied to a screen must reflect some state of this screen, we would like to share a `ViewModel` between them. Same goes for the top bar.

The above restrictions necessarily mean that the instance of a desired `ViewModel` must be created outside the scope of all mentioned composables and as such **outside** the `NavHost` and its scoped `ViewModelStore`s, which is a huge problem because the only other `ViewModelStore` is the one owned by the Activity, which in a single-activity pattern **is never cleared**! So every shared `ViewModel` effectively becomes a singleton and a memory leak, aside from weird bugs it causes (sate that needed to be updated by creating a new instance but wasn't). What I actually want is for shared view models to be destroyed when user leaves the screen it is tied to, but it doesn't seem possible.

So is this even possible to fix this problem without changing the structure of the UI (and such dealing with other problems that led to it in the first place)? Does it even needs fixing? Are singleton view models OK provided state-related bugs are fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After almost half a year of nobody answering this question the issue became critical in my project, so I started looking for solutions. After days of googling I was almost ready for a battle to the death with Android Framework through reflection to manually add and remove view models to/from `Activity`'s `ViewModelStore`, but thankfully I found a one-liner solution.
I use Hilt in my project, so to get destination-scoped `ViewModel`s I use the following extension function:

```kotlin
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavBackStackEntry.hiltViewModel() =
    ViewModelProvider(
        this.viewModelStore,
        HiltViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current, this)
    )[T::class.java]
```

```kotlin
private fun NavGraphBuilder.projectsGraph() {
    navigation(
        startDestination = AppTab.Projects.startDestination,
        route = AppTab.Projects.route
    ) {
        composable(AppScreen.Projects.route) {
            Projects()
        }

        composable(AppScreen.ProjectDetails.route) {
            ProjectDetails(projectViewModel = it.hiltViewModel()) // <--
        }
    }
}
```

Hilt creates a `ViewModel` instance based on the information inside a `NavBackStackEntry` object inside its own scoped `ViewModelStore`, and we can get this object through `NavHostContoller.currentBackStackEntry`!

I already had a `CompositionLocal` for `NavHostContoller` for convenience:

```kotlin
val LocalNavController = compositionLocalOf<NavHostController> {
    throw IllegalStateException("NavController does not yet exist")
}
```

```kotlin
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalNavController provides rememberNavController()
) {
    RootComposable()
}
```

So the only thing left to do is to create another function that gets a `ViewModel` created for a given `NavBackStackEntry`:

```kotlin
/**
 * Returns an existing [ViewModel] for the current navigation destination
 * regardless of where in the composition you want it :)
 */
@Composable
internal inline fun <reified VM: ViewModel> screenViewModel() =
    LocalNavController.current.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.hiltViewModel<VM>()
```

As a result, provided your `LocalNavController` provides to your app bars and bottom sheet, you can simply do the following and get the same instance of a `ViewModel` inside and outside of navigation graph.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ProjectTopAppBar(
    viewModel: ProjectViewModel = screenViewModel()
) {
    viewModel ?: return
    // ...
}
```

Even better, it won't be a memory leak because it is still attached to a destination.

Comment: what if i get this error  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by 'SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`

Comment: That's a Hilt/Navigation interop problem. Try those solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73302605/creationextras-must-have-a-value-by-saved-state-registry-owner-key